# Linked Server: Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_INDEXES" for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, msdasql

When selecting from a certain tables in Teradata from SQL Server Management Studio, over an ODBC Linked Server Connection

For certain tables I get the above error, for others i don't. It seems random.

Error Details:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TD" returned message
>   "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available. No work was done.".
>       Msg 7311, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>       Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_INDEXES" for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TD". The provider supports the
>   interface, but returns a failure code when it is used.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[linked]` and `[server]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[linked-server]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: thanks @Charles, new here, now i know how to add tags with more than one word

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was to rename the tables to something shorter than 25 characters. Or to create a view with a name shorter than 25 characters selecting from the original table.

This would be also fixed if you do:

select from Openquery(TD, 'select from db.Table')

instead of

select from TD..db.Table